# Does dnf autoremove remove only unused packages/dependencies?

Tags: linux, fedora, dependencies, dnf

Does `dnf remove` only remove packages which aren't part of other dependencies? I removed `gnome-boxes` because I like vmware better but it removed a *ton* of dependencies, which made me wonder; i.e. `gnome-boxes` were dependent on `capstone`, if I had other software installed which were dependent on the latter, would `capstone` have been removed anyway?

Comment: I never  had any issue with sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove which includes an update to prevent issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly how `dnf` (and other package managers) works. And if something depends on `gnome-boxes`, removing `gnome-boxes` would also remove it.

You can use `--noautoremove` to prevent this from happening and later run `dnf autoremove` to remove all "leaf" packages (packages from the system that were originally installed as dependencies of user-installed packages, but which are no longer required by any such package).